# MariaDb: JSON_ARRAY_APPEND to empty array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, mariadb

I find it confusing (and not working) to use JSON_ARRAY_APPEND with empty JSON arrays according to the docs. I'm using newest version of MariaDb 10.2.6.

When I do:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[1]', '$', JSON_EXTRACT('{"test":123}', '$'));
```

Result is as expected:

```
[1, {"test": 123}]
```

(the same with:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_EXTRACT('[1]', '$'), '$', JSON_EXTRACT('{"test":123}', '$'));
```

)

But, when I operate on empty array:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[]', '$', JSON_EXTRACT('{"test":123}', '$'));
```

The result is:

```
(NULL)
```

Probably because of this I cannot update field with empty array. When I do:

```
UPDATE `test` SET `test`.`log` = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(`test`.`log`, '$', JSON_EXTRACT('{"test":123}', '$'))
```

I get an error:

```
(4038) Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_array_append' at position 2
```

Am I getting something wrong or is it some kind of bug or caveat?

Regards,
JK.

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_ARRAY(''), '$', JSON_EXTRACT('{"test":123}', '$'))\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_ARRAY(''), '$', JSON_EXTRACT('{"test":123}', '$')): ["", {"test": 123}]
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are right. This is what docs are saying. But I'm not talking about NULL, I'm talking about empty array `[]`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but not really. I store it in field. Default value is `[]`. I need it to be working with this.

Comment: I think mariadb has different treat for `[]` and `JSON_ARRAY(’’)`, and they has different meaning.

Comment: It does treat in this case. But it should not. `JSON_EXTRACT('[]', '$')` should === `JSON_ARRAY(’’)`.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a bug.

Comment: this array thing is still a bug for me, even for 10.2.9

Comment: I stumbled upon this bug too, but let me tell you, `json_array() !== json_array('')`. Both represent different things. `json_array()` is `[]` (empty array) while `json_array('')` is `[""]` (array length one, with empty string)

Comment: crazy, I am on mariadb 10.2.17 and in the bug you linked they said it was fixed on mariadb 10.2.9 and closed it. But I still get the same bug

Comment: Probably this one: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17121